# What Programming language should I use to build app similar to duolingo for Android, iOS, Desktop, and web

Tags: javascript, python, desktop-application, mobile-application

I'm looking to build a app related around education similar to duolingo. Currently, I know Python  and a tiny bit of Javascript. but I was wondering what programming language (not just limited to Python and JS) should I use / learn to build this app for iOS, ANDROID, Website, and DESKTOP? I dont think learning a hard language like C++ is really realistic. Thanks!

Is there one programming that I can use to do all of the things I mentioned above?

Comment: It would just be simpler to develop a webpage and have handling for different screens. However, there are cross-platform tools like Xamarin, Flutter, React. 
 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cross-platform-frameworks.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **DART programming** language.You can use **[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) or [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)**. Both of them are **cross-platform** application-building tools.